# qplot barplot overlaps bars, how to avoid that?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm creating a barplot with following code:

```
qplot(forest_visit, data = W522, geom = "bar",
   fill=sex,xlab= "Waldbesuche",ylab="Anzahl der Probanden")+ geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

This is the result:

[image]

What I want is the red and blue bars next to each other, not the blue bar inside the red bar.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: For completeness sake. please add some sample data as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Please do some research and give internet resources at least a try before you ask**. I also couldn't use your data because you didn't share it.

Therefore I just use the sample data from the linked website. I didn't create this I just googled

> stacked grouped barchart ggplot

and found [this](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2/):

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a sample dataset
specie=c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition=rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value=abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data=data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# Grouped
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Generally speaking you do not use the `qplot` function in ggplot to plot. You use the `ggplot` function. In that function you specify the data you use and in `aes` you define the `x`- and/or `y`-Axis. In this case you set a group with the `fill`-argument.